# Input via console to control byte values

Tags: .net

I have this code to control an led strip,

```
using MagicHome;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MagicHome.Example
{
    class GetStarted
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var discoveredLights = await Light.DiscoverAsync();

            if (discoveredLights?.Count > 0)
            {
                var light = discoveredLights[0];

                //Connect.
                await light.ConnectAsync();

                //Check if it is ON.
                if (light.Power == false)
                    await light.TurnOnAsync();

                //Change color to green.
                await light.SetColorAsync(0, 255, 0);

                //Print to console light's status.
                Console.WriteLine(light.ToString());
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine if I manually input the byte values but I was wondering if it would be possible to input them via the console?

Comment: `byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`?

Comment: Thanks i just added `byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` and created 3 byte variables and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```cs
byte b1;
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number:");
    if(byte.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b1))
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
}
```